# How to make the base class call overriden function from child class

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance

I have a class name `Piece` which has a number of children classes like `Rook`, `Knight`, `King` etc...
The class `Piece` has a virtual function named `Move(int x, int y)` and all the child classes inherit this function.
Now I have another function, let's call it `foo(Piece& src, Piece& dest)`. `foo()` calls the the function `move()` this way:

```
int foo(Piece& src, Piece& dest)
{
    int moveCode = src.move(dest.getX(), dest.getY());
    // Rest of the code ...
}
```

The function `foo()` sometimes gets `knight` class as a parameter, or `King` class, or the rest of the child classes.
My problem is when I call `move()` I want it to call the overridden `move` function from the child class and instead it calls the `move` class from `Piece` the base class.
Is there any way to make `src.move()` call the child function?

Piece.h:

```
class Piece
{
    protected:
        int _pieceTypeIndex;
        int _pieceColor;
        int _x;
        int _y;
    public:
        Piece();
        Piece(int x, int y);
        Piece(int x, int y, int pieceTypeIndex, int pieceColor);
        virtual int move(int dest_x, int dest_y);
        int getPieceTypeIndex() const;
        int getPieceColor() const;
        void setPieceTypeIndex(int pieceTypeIndex);
        void setPieceColor(int pieceColor);
        int getX();
        int getY();
        void setX(int x);
        void setY(int y);
        Piece& operator=(Piece& other);
};
```

Child class code (Rook.h):

```
class Rook : public Piece
{
public:
    Rook(int x, int y, int pieceTypeIndex, int pieceColor);
    virtual int move(int dest_x, int dest_y);
};
```

Comment: @Mat Sorry, that's a mistake in the code I wrote here, the `Board& board` is not there in the code. I got blacked out and accidentally copied it. I fixed the question now.

Comment: Unrelated: I don't see a need for the assignment operator. Writing an assignment operator when you don't need to opens up the possibility for avoidable bugs. If you do need it for reasons left out of the above, then [the Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) suggests you have a Copy Constructor and a destructor to go with it.

Comment: @0xBlackMirror Did you make anything out of the answers you got?

Answer (score 0):

The signatures differs. They need to be the same. Your `Rook` needs to become this:

```
class Rook : public Piece
{
public:
    Rook(int x, int y, int pieceTypeIndex, int pieceColor);
    virtual int move(int dest_x, int dest_y);
};
```

A good trick to validate you are doing it correctly is to use the keyword `override`.

```
class Rook : public Piece
{
public:
    Rook(int x, int y, int pieceTypeIndex, int pieceColor);
    virtual int move(int dest_x, int dest_y) override;
    virtual int move(int dest_x, int dest_y, Board& board) override; //Wouldn't compile
};
```

Comment: Sorry thats a mistake in the code I wrote here, the `Board& board` is not there in the code. I got blacked out and accidentally copied it. I fixed the question now.

Comment: @0xBlackMirror That code would work if it's really like that.

Comment: @Rosme, one reasons I dont overload functions, is when mixed with virtual / overriding

Comment: @umlcat This is just example code to show him. However this answer doesn't fit anymore considering that he changed the code of the original question.

Comment: @Rosme But when `src.move(dest.getX(), dest.getY())` is called, it still call the original function from `Piece` and not from the children.

Comment: @0xBlackMirror From the code you provided, that wouldn't be the case. Either you didn't compile that code, or the implementation inside your `Rook::move` is the same as your `Piece`. A good way to test out if it's really calling `Piece::move` is to make it pure virtual `= 0;`

Comment: @Rosme There is no way is implementation is the same. In `Piece` I just put a `return 1;` line just for testing, but in `Rook::move()` I wrote a fully operational function. And the code I provided is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

> How to make the base class call overriden function from child class

You simply call it - and if the base class has no idea of how to perform any part of the task, make the function pure virtual (which also makes your base class abstract - it can't be instantiated, which is a good thing). Also try to avoid magic numbers. Name the things you can to make it easier to read the code.

You can also rely on the implicitly created copy constructors/assignment operators in this case. All the types used inside your base class are trivially copyable.

Here's an example of how you can split up your `move()` function into one base class part and one part that only the derived classes can handle, the validation of the move, and have the base class `move()` call `validate_move()` in the derived class.

```
#include <iostream>

// name stuff
enum piece_t { rook, knight, king /* etc */ };
enum color_t { c_black, c_white };

class Piece {
    private:
        // You probably can make these private:
        piece_t _pieceTypeIndex;
        color_t _pieceColor;
        int _x;
        int _y;

    protected:
        // No need to have this public - it's never going to be used by anything
        // but derived classes.
        Piece(int x, int y, color_t pieceColor, piece_t pieceTypeIndex) :
            _pieceTypeIndex(pieceTypeIndex),
            _pieceColor(pieceColor),
            _x(x),
            _y(y)
        {}

    public:
        Piece() = default; // this is questionable

        // Pure virtual - must be implemented by derived classes
        virtual bool validate_move(int dest_x, int dest_y) = 0;

        bool move(int dest_x, int dest_y) {
            // Call the validate_move function in the derived class
            if(validate_move(dest_x, dest_y)==false) return false;

            // Do the rest of the stuff that happens when you move
            // that the base class can actually handle
            _x = dest_x;
            _y = dest_y;
            return true;
        }

        int getX() const { return _x; }
        int getY() const { return _y; }

        // the rest of the functions excluded for brevity
};

class Rook : public Piece {
public:
    using Piece::Piece; // use base class constructors (default ctor - perhaps not needed)

    // The Rook constructor only needs position and color since it already knows
    // that it's a rook and can supply that info to the base class constructor.
    Rook(int x, int y, color_t c) : Piece(x, y, c, rook) {}

    // Implementation of the function that's pure virtual in base.
    // Use "override" to make sure that you actually override. Then compiler
    // will complain if you try to override something that isn't virtual.
    bool validate_move(int /*dest_x*/, int /*dest_y*/) override {
        // validate if this move is ok or not
        return true;
    }
};

int main() {
    Rook a(2, 1, c_black); // no need to specify pieceTypeIndex
    Rook b;                // default, uninitialized - not even a proper Rook at this time
    b = a;                 // copy assignment - now it's a Rook
    Rook c(b);             // copy construction

    std::cout << c.getX() << ' ' << c.getY() << '\n';

    if(c.move(3,4))        // silly move for a rook, but validate_move approves anything :)
        std::cout << "successfully moved to " << c.getX() << ' ' << c.getY() << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare the same function / method in the **base** class, mark that function as `virtual`, and redeclare that same function in a child class, marked both with the `virtual` and `override` keywords.

```
**Pieces.hpp**

class Piece
{
  // ...

  public:

  virtual int move (int x, int y);

  void start(int x, int y);

  // ...

  } // class

class Rook : public Piece
{
  // ...

  public:

  virtual int move (int x, int y) override;

  // ...

  } // class

**Pieces.cpp**

void piece::start(int x, int y)
{
  this::move(x, y);
} //
```

But, this CANNOT be done in the constructor method in "C++".

```
int main (...)
{
  Piece MyPiece = new Rook( );
  MyPiece->Start(1, 1);
  free MyPiece ( );

  return 0;
}
```

You also use another function, with same ID, and additional parameters, it works, but developers get confused.